# dispatch_queue and return data

Tags: ios, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to write this method that returns an `NSArray`. My `NSMutableArray` (friendUsers) adds the objects right, but outside the dispatch_async the array is empty.
I try to add the users in the main queue ( as ashowed) but the array is empty to. Any ideas ? Thanks for all your help.

```
- (NSArray *)checkUsersInGroup {

    NSMutableArray *friendUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t checkUSers = dispatch_queue_create("CheckUsers", NULL);
    dispatch_async(checkUSers, ^{

        NSArray *totalUsers = [VVDataRead lecturaDades];
        NSArray *usersToSearch = [_grup objectForKey:@"groupFriends"];

        for (NSString *tempUserId in usersToSearch){
            for (NSDictionary *user in totalUsers){
                NSString *id = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
                    if ([tempUserId isEqualToString:id])
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [friendUsers addObject:user];
                        });
            }
        }

    });
    NSLog(@"people:%@",friendUsers);
    return [friendUsers copy];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use blocks, it can make your life easier in this case.

```
- (void)checkUsersInGroupWithCompleteBlock:(void(^)(NSMutableArray * resultArray))completeBlock {

    NSMutableArray *friendUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t checkUSers = dispatch_queue_create("CheckUsers", NULL);
    dispatch_async(checkUSers, ^{

        NSArray *totalUsers = [VVDataRead lecturaDades];
        NSArray *usersToSearch = [_grup objectForKey:@"groupFriends"];

        for (NSString *tempUserId in usersToSearch){
            for (NSDictionary *user in totalUsers){
                NSString *id = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
                if ([tempUserId isEqualToString:id])
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [friendUsers addObject:user];
                    });
            }
        }

        // call the complete block with the result when you finished
        if (completeBlock) completeBlock(friendUsers);
    });
}
```

...and here is how you can call the method:

```
- (void)anyMethod {

    // ... do whetever you want here before

    [self checkUsersInGroupWithCompleteBlock:^(NSMutableArray *resultArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);
    }];

    // ... or after

}
```

---

**EDITED:**

*NOTE: here is another possible solution, but in your case it just suspends the main thread (which is definitely **bad**), so you won't gain anything with this solution but pain on the main thread, but if you are on two background threads, this solution can give a very nice example of synchronisation between the threads.*

```
- (NSArray *)checkUsersInGroup {

    NSMutableArray *friendUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // our semaphore is here
    dispatch_semaphore_t _semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    dispatch_queue_t checkUSers = dispatch_queue_create("CheckUsers", NULL);
    dispatch_async(checkUSers, ^{

        NSArray *totalUsers = [VVDataRead lecturaDades];
        NSArray *usersToSearch = [_grup objectForKey:@"groupFriends"];

        for (NSString *tempUserId in usersToSearch){
            for (NSDictionary *user in totalUsers){
                NSString *id = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
                if ([tempUserId isEqualToString:id])
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [friendUsers addObject:user];
                    });
            }
        }
        // the process finished
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);

    });

    // ... we are wainitng for the semaphore's signal
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(_semaphore);

    NSLog(@"people:%@",friendUsers);
    return [friendUsers copy];

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, very useful answer, I'm new to blocks stuff and it confused me a lot !

Comment: no problem, if you have nay question, don't keep them inside your mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are number of strategies to solve this, but as your operation happens on a background thread, returning the array isn't one of them. You could use `NSNotificationCenter` to signal that the task as finished and read the array. i.e.

```
- (void)checkUsersInGroup {

    NSMutableArray *friendUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t checkUSers = dispatch_queue_create("CheckUsers", NULL);
    dispatch_async(checkUSers, ^{

        NSArray *totalUsers = [VVDataRead lecturaDades];
        NSArray *usersToSearch = [_grup objectForKey:@"groupFriends"];

        for (NSString *tempUserId in usersToSearch){
            for (NSDictionary *user in totalUsers){
                NSString *id = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
                    if ([tempUserId isEqualToString:id])
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [friendUsers addObject:user];
                        });
            }
        }

        // Signal background task is finished
        // Make sure to add an observer to this notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"friendsAddLiteral"
                                                                object:nil];

    });
}

//this method will respond to the notification
- (void) onFriendsAdded:(NSNotification*)notif {
    //do something on the main thread
}
```